# How can I concatenate multiple fields in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

What is the actual function to generate a single line output (Column I, #QR) from below fields?

| + | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | f_name | l_name | designation | email | landline | mobile | country | web | #QR |
| 2 | John | DOE | Senior Manager | john.doe@gmail.com | 4422688 | 444221 | Sweden | google.com | BEGIN:VCARD\nVERSION:2.1\nFN:John Doe\nORG:Senior Manager - Google\nADR:Sweden\nTEL;WORK:4422688\nTEL;CELL:444221\nEMAIL:john.doe@gmail.com\nURL:google.lk\nEND:VCARD |

Answer (score 0):

There is a function "Textjoin" if you're using Excel 2019 or up:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,A1:A2)
```

This would result into the string "f_nameJohn". You can look up more about this function here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
=A2&B2
```

giving JohnDOE

Then you can do:

```
=A2&" "&B2
```

which will put a space between: John DOE

Answer (score 0):

if you don't have Excel 2019 or up you can use:

```
   =A2&" "&B2&" "&C2&" "&D2&" "&E2&" "&F2&" "&G2&" "&H2&" "&I2
```

or

```
=CONCATENATE(A2," ",B2," ",C2," ",D2," ",E2," ",F2," ",G2," ",H2," ",I2)
```